# TinyMCE not working after partial postback in update panel

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, updatepanel, partial-postback

I am trying to use TinyMCE editor with my text area in an update panel. On the first page load it works fine, but as soon as the update panel updates the text area lost its formatting and become a simple text area than a rich text editor.

I have tried some solutions but it did not worked. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Best Regards,

Comment: Try moving your initialization to a `pageLoad` function you create for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your tinyMce again after each partial postback. You can do this by using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            BindEvents();
            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
            prm.add_endRequest(function () {
                BindEvents();
            });
        });
```

And on your BindEvents() function place your code for initilize tinyMce or any other events you want to keep alive after the postback.

```
function BindEvents() {
//bind your jquery events and TinyMce initialization
}
```

Comment: Dear Issac, I tried this technique but unfortunately it did not worked for me :( i appreciate your response. Thanks :)